# Python starmap got multiple values for argument

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, starmap

I hava a multiprocess program whcich using `starmap`. But when I run it, a `TypeError` occured. While normally when I run it in `map`.

```py
def process_single_image(img_path, target_dir="", func=None, severity=1):
    print(target_dir)
    ...
```

```py
pool.starmap(
    partial(
        process_single_image,
        target_dir=target_dir,
        func=iaa.imgcorruptlike.apply_shot_noise,
        severity=4,
    ),
    img_paths,
)
```

I don't know why I got this error. I think it should run normally as `pool.map(....)`.
Here is the traceback.
[image]

Comment: Maybe share the stack with us?

Comment: Sure. I just add the screenshot of traceback in original post.

Comment: I conjecture that whether `starmap()` pass throug 2 arguments at least?

Comment: What does `img_paths` look like? It has to be an iterable of iterables. Also, post the traceback in text form rather than in an image.

Comment: It's a list. you can use any string list for test. such as img_path =['abc','ab',..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `.starmap` are unpacked to the target function. Therefore, the arguments must be an *iterable* of *iterables* (even if the argument length the target function accepts is one).

Therefore, if the argument length is one, then explicitly convert each element of `img_path` into a tuple before passing it to starmap:

```
img_path = [(arg,) for arg in img_path]
```